# Get Key values from a file by using linq query

Tags: c#, linq

There are multiple files in a folder that the code should read one by one. I have to extract some key value from the file to perform some business logic.

the file look like this,

```
x-sender: 
x-receiver: 
Received: 
X-AuditID:
Received: 
Received: 
From: 
To: 
Subject: 
Thread-Topic: 
Thread-Index: 
Date: 
Message-ID: 
Accept-Language: 
Content-Language: 
X-MS-Has-Attach:
```

There are multiple keys that can increase and decrease as per file. The order of the key could also be changed. Every key has some value.

Code:

```
 private void BtnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // searches current directory

                foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(NetWorkPath, "*.eml"))
                {

                    var dic = File.ReadAllLines(file)
                                .Select(l => l.Split(new[] { ':' }))
                                .ToDictionary(s => s[0].Trim(), s => s[1].Trim());
                    string myUser = dic["From"];

            }
        }
```

I was trying to read the file and convert that into dictionary , So that i can access by using Keys. But it is giving me an error `"An item with the same key has already been added.".`

Any help??

Comment: So can you share a piece of code with ToLookUp.

Comment: ankur, I added as an answer.

Comment: What should the code do if in some line text after the colon does not exist? Or if there no colon in the line? Or if there is an empty line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `ToDictionary`, You can use `ToLookup`

```
......same code....
.Where(s => s.Length>1)
.ToLookup(s => s[0].Trim(), s => s[1].Trim());
```

Then you can check as

```
string myUser = dic["From"].FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: it is giving an error of   'Index out of bound error' in 's[1].Trim()'

Comment: @ankur, your code would give the same error too, since there may be blank lines in your file(most probably et the end). Make sure `s.Length>1` with a `Where`. (`.Where(s=>s.Length>1).ToLookup(...)`)

Comment: there are some blank spaces, can you update your answer with the where clause....

Comment: Thanks @i4v it is working , I will check for rest of the keys and update you.

Answer (score 2):

That's because `Receieved` is in there multiple times and `Dictionary` doesn't allow duplicate entries for it's key value.

You could use a [`Tuple<string, string>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx), that would allow duplicates.

If you don't want to return it though, you could just use an anonymous type:

```
foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(NetWorkPath, "*.eml"))
{

    var items = myList
        .Select(l => l.Split(new [] {':' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
        .Where(l => l != null && l.Count() == 2)
        .Select(l => new
        {
            Key = l[0],
            Value = l[1],
        })
        .ToList();

    string myUser = items.First(i => i.Key == "From").Value;
}
```

Comment: yes you are correct but it is system generated files that will contain some duplicates. Can you post an example of LINQ query using tuples for the same scenario....

Comment: @ankur Check my edit, if you're not returning (which I don't think you are), then you can use anonymous types.

Comment: 's[0]' was giving an error of 's' is not defined . So I replaces 's' with 'l' that we used in previous lamda expression. Not it is giving me an 'Index out of bound error' in 'key=l[0].Trim()'.....

Comment: @ankur Apologies, that was my variable naming! Try now

Comment: There are some blank lines may be that is the reason can we filter by adding a where clause to it, I am not able to figure our whare exactly i have to put the where clause for filtering it by length.... can you suggest ....

Comment: @ankur Added a `Where` to make sure all of the data is there (preventing errors).

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 elements with a same name - **Received:**

Answer (score 0):

It is means that you have already added in dictionary the same key twice,
for content of your file it is Received: